# ModuleNotFoundError at /blog/post/comment/update/18/ No module named 'test-post-ecomon'

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a blog section of my website and I made an CommentUpdateView and after submiting the form it gives me this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError at /blog/post/comment/update/18/
No module named 'test-post-ecomon'
```

but I don't undersant why because this post exists and I implemented get_absolute_url in my Contact models and It should work right? When I create a new commment it works.

view

```
class CommentUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Comment
    form_class = CommentUpdateForm
    template_name = 'blog/update_comment.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(author=self.request.user)
```

model

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    reply = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='replies')
    content = models.TextField(_('Content'))
    posted_date = models.DateTimeField(_('Posted Date/Time'), auto_now_add=True)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(_('Updated Date/Time'), auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.author.username} - {self.post.title}'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post', self.post.slug)
```

urls

```
path('post/<slug:slug>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post'),
path('post/comment/update/<int:pk>/', CommentUpdateView.as_view(), name='update-comment'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting your `get_absolute_url` like this:

```
def get_absolute_url(request):
    return reverse('post', args=(self.post.slug, ))
```

P.S. *You dont really want to reassign user in your update view since it decreases performance whilte doing basically nothing*